# Is it a good idea to add .Net Framework class library to .Net core console application

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-framework-version

I have created a new .net core console application and, I have all my BL and DAL in a NuGet package which is in .net Framework(some class libraries in this are in .Net framework 2.0). if I install this NuGet in .Core library it will not work fine which is obvious.

so the question is, if I add a .Net Framework(4.7) class library and install this Nuget and EFCore in it are there anything that would go wrong? will I be able to consume this class library in .Net core console application.

what I have done so far:

I have added the .net framework class library to solution installed the this NuGet and EF Core, I don't see any error in the class library.

Comment: Please look for similar questions. Questions like this have been asked and answered before.

Comment: Possible? Yes. Good idea? Probably not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's a bad idea and it won't work.

Any .NET Framework compiled libraries can't be used and referenced in .NET Core projects and vice versa.

You can do it with NuGet packages, but it would be a good idea to reduce the risk of failure by converting the code to .NET Standard.
Because then you can use safely in .NET Core as long as your .NET Framework class library doesn't contain non-.NET Standard namespaces and classes.

See this official .NET Standard compatibility references: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Also you can check manually the API compatibility by going to this: 
https://apisof.net

**UPDATE 1:**
Thanks to Jon Skeet's comment, looks like there is a way to reference .NET Framework into .NET Core by using nuget packages targeting .NET Framework!

See 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/third-party-deps#net-framework-compatibility-mode

But there's still a chance that it might not work, especially if the third party libraries uses classes that only available in .NET Framework that's not ported to .NET Core such as Workflow Foundation and server-side WCF.

I'm not going to delete my answer, because I have to keep my answer as a lesson for me as well :)

**UPDATE 2**: reword to update from only way to doable with NuGet package reference as suggested by Jon.

Comment: "Any .NET Framework compiled libraries can't be used and referenced in .NET Core projects and vice versa." As of .NET Core 2.0, you can use NuGet packages targeting .NET Framework - although they might not work. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/third-party-deps#net-framework-compatibility-mode (linked to from the doc you referred to...)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Jon! Yes, I missed that. Updating my answer.

Comment: While I wouldn't delete the answer, I think it's worth just updating it to have the correct information in (and removing the last bit). I'd also still *suggest* changing the library to target netstandard instead, as a generally good idea.

Comment: yes, I also already suggested to migrate the .NET Framework class libraries to .NET Standard first.

Comment: Well currently you say that's the *only* option. Instead, I'd expect the answer to be "You *can* do it with NuGet packages, but it would be a good idea to reduce the risk of failure by converting the code to .NET Standard."

Comment: Thanks again! You're so kind to correct my answer! Sure, I'll update my answer now.